# How to use viewGroup in android

Tags: android

How    to   use  viewGroup   in android

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) is a documentation from Google

Comment: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/05/create-dynamic-view-group.html This example is OK. Be sure to set unique id-s for such views when using them in `ListView`, or they can be redrawn on scrolling

Comment: `ViewGroup` is any group of views literally, - `ListView`, `Linear`/`Horizontal`/`VerticalLayout` ..., all these kinds. What example do you want? Adding or removing views?

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned, ViewGroup is an abstract class that all ViewGroups extend, LinearLayout for instance is a ViewGroup.

**MyViewGroup.java:**

```
public class MyViewGroup extends LinearLayout {

    public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        Log.e("SWIPED", "onLayout : " + Boolean.toString(changed));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        Log.e("SWIPED", "onInterceptTouchEvent : " + event.getAction());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Main.XML:**

```
<com.example.MyViewGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TEXT ONE"
    android:padding="20dip" android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

<TextView android:padding="20dip" android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:id="@+id/tv2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT TWO" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</com.example.MyViewGroup>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: The MyViewGroup class here does nothing , prints nothing.

Comment: I do not think this answer can give any help to anyone else. Since the it extends the `LinearLayout`, and all those jobs should be overridden is thrown to `LinearLayout`. It make no senses.

Comment: The idea is to show what a ViewGroup is, via placeholder code. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Can you explain onLayout() method?