# Android: Tutorial on Custom View creation

Tags: android, uiview

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial about how to create custom view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was asking myself the same question. Doing a searches on Google, I found some good info. First of all you should start by reading the documentation presented by Google Android:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

After that, for general tutorials of a view that extends the `android.view.View` class, these seem to be good examples:

- http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/08/creatingcustomviews/
- http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/20/creating-a-custom-widgets-in-android/

As for using the `android.view.ViewGroup`, there seems to be already some posts on the subject:

- [How to use viewGroup in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367983/how-to-use-viewgroup-in-android)
- [custom ViewGroup example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663068/custom-viewgroup-example-please)
- [Can anyone give a good example of a Custom ViewGroup containing a Custom View with measure and layout examples? (In Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812549/can-anyone-give-a-good-example-of-a-custom-viewgroup-containing-a-custom-view-wi)

Comment: I think this better addresses the issues of creating a totally custom view versus just creating sub-views or extending another view.

Answer (score 7):

Custom View - HorizontalSlider | Hello Android

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/custom-view-horizontalslider

Comment: The last 2 links have nothing to do with the question?!

Comment: looks like he just did a google search for you and didn't check the results.