# Android - Adding layouts to a parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 layout xml files: "highlights.xml" and "highlights_cell.xml".

Here is a simplified version of each. I've removed the width/height/etc and just kept the important attributes...

**highlights.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
  <uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools.ui.SwipeView android:id="@+id/swipe_view" />
  <uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools.ui.PageControl android:id="@+id/page_control" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**highlights_cell.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout1" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout2" android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView android:id="@+id/title" />
      <TextView android:id="@+id/subtitle" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll_view">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/description" />
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The idea is that I want to add several "highlights_cell" to "highlights" through a loop.

I've thrown together some test code as follows but, as it's not working, I suspect that I'm not adding the cell layouts correctly, or perhaps I shouldn't be using "inflater"...

```
/** Declare shared variables */
SwipeView mSwipeView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    //Initialise layout and variables
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highlights);

    //Setup controls
    mSwipeView = (SwipeView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_view);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Loop through collection and add views
    for(int i=0; i<7;i++)
    {
        //Create the itemView to use layout xml for each cell  
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.highlights_cell, null);

        //Set values within cell
        TextView title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText("HELLO WORLD_" + i);

        //add the itemView to main view
        mSwipeView.addView(itemView);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to add layouts dynamically to a parent layout?
Thanks!

Comment: At a glance this code looks fine. You should add in all the original attributes (width/height/etc) as these may be the source of the issue.

Comment: I use the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) which you can take a look at too. It has adapter support which is useful for large data sets.

Comment: thanks for the comments .. I looked at ViewPager but I couldn't find an example with a PageControl equivalent (dots under the view that track your position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good except for a few things.

Because you are adding views to your custom [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), you will have to be sure that it correctly lays out and displays its children.

Also, when you add a `View` to a `ViewGroup`, you specify the [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) that views can have in that `ViewGroup`.

Some more info about creating a custom `ViewGroup`

- http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/05/create-dynamic-view-group.html
- [custom ViewGroup example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663068/custom-viewgroup-example-please)