# Android - Adding buttons to the title

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface, themes, android-titlebar

Please, let me know, how to add buttons to the title bar.

- Remove the title completely and create a custom title with an ImageView for example.

*or*

- Use another approach

My Goal is something similar to the Facebook app
[image]

**UPDATE:**
API Level >= 10

Comment: I usually make my own title bar, so I can add buttons, status icon... Need to code your own ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I was wondering if this is the best practice approach?

Comment: This link can be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663068/custom-viewgroup-example-please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it's best practice to use Android's Actionbar.
Prefer action menu instead of buttons in custom title bar.

Please see : [image: There's given refresh and edit action menu]

And for the further implementation of actionbar please refer :

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html
2. developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html‎

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my question ... API level 10 is my minimum version.

Comment: Yeah..! There's option to give support from API level 8, you can use SherlockActionbar library..

Please download library from : http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

My solution using custom ViewGroup (from RelativeLayout) so I can use it in different activities without copy paste xml. This is a simple example that update a text view with the title. You can add buttons to relative layout ang get them work in the way you need.

**But if you've only an Activity it's better if you include it as a sub layout of the main layout of your activity**

```
public class StatusBar extends RelativeLayout {

private TextView textViewTitle;

    public StatusBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ui_status_bar, this, true);
        super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
}

private void updateStatusBar(String title) {
this.textViewTitle.setText(title)
}
}
```

And the ui_status_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/theme_color_darker"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in your activity you can use it like this:

```
<com.uicomponents.statusbar.StatusBar
    android:id="@+id/statusBar"
    style="@style/status_bar" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to make it clear:R.layout.ui_status_bar is a reference to the XML? can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It's hard to explain if you have no experience with custm View and viewGroups. layout.ui_status_bar.xml goes into layout/ folder in the Android project. when you compile, that layour can be loaded by its reference from the resources (i.e. R.layout.ui_status_bar) like you do ehn loading layout for the activity.